# OpenRefine: create a shifted copy of a column

Tags: python, openrefine, grel

I wonder if OpenRefine lets you access data from other rows, when creating a new column. I suspect it does not (and it would be a sane design principle) but there could be a hack around that.

Here is an example of what one could want to do: shifting a column by one row.

I have the following table:

```
╔═════╦════════╗
║ row ║ Model  ║
╠═════╬════════╣
║   1 ║ Quest  ║
║   2 ║ DF     ║
║   3 ║ Waw    ║
║   4 ║ Strada ║
╚═════╩════════╝
```

And I want to obtain the following result:

```
╔═════╦════════╦══════════╗
║ row ║ Model  ║ Previous ║
╠═════╬════════╬══════════╣
║   1 ║ Quest  ║          ║
║   2 ║ DF     ║ Quest    ║
║   3 ║ Waw    ║ DF       ║
║   4 ║ Strada ║ Waw      ║
╚═════╩════════╩══════════╝
```

Looking at https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Variables it seems that there isn't any variable that would let you access information outside the current row or record, so I wonder if this sort of operation is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no "column" variable in Open Refine. A possible workaround would be to turn all the dataset into a single record, then apply a bit of Python/Jython.

Example:

```
data = row['record']['cells']['Model']['value']
for i, el in enumerate(data):
    if value == el and i !=0:
        return data[i - 1]
```

Screencast:

[image]

I don't know if a solution in GREL is possible.

Comment: Thanks! I think that is a very sensible design decision, as it ensures that the operations can be applied to rows independently of the context. This means, for instance, that one could use something like pyrefine to apply a set of OpenRefine operations on a data stream (a table which would be discovered gradually, in a sense). I think it is a very powerful paradigm for a lot of Wikidata bots.