# Compare two lists for differences with openrefine

Tags: openrefine

Given the following data:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GCbhf8w3cwJYi1gNWUTw4eW0qhGvTGBjpzlkwtCHbH8/edit#gid=0
how could one have reported the differences between the two columns?

We need to know in the second column, which values were added, and which were deleted. Here is the way to do the same with google sheets (i face performance issues though, since my lists are huge...)

https://www.prolificoaktree.com/google-sheets-compare-two-lists-for-matches-or-differences/

Comment: I would upvote this question (I'm not going to downvote it, regardless), but your question relies on an external link to the data. I suggest putting an example of the data in the body of the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

1° Add a *first empty column* in the dataset and write anything in the *first cell* of that column, [like this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ql42ON7DDxTYpYto1EFn0u86zqxMqwOD_WAY5VKtTjE/edit?usp=sharing).

2° Import the dataset into OpenRefine. Make sure you have only one record.

[image]

3° Create a new column ("Edit column --> Add column based on this column") by checking the "Python/Jython" box and use this script (modify the column names to match those of your real dataset).

```
original = row.record.cells["Column 2"].value
modified = row.record.cells["Column 3"].value

if value not in list(set(original) & set(modified)):
    return "new element"
```

[image]

4° If your data is really huge, consider [giving more memory to OpenRefine](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/FAQ:-Allocate-More-Memory).

---

For a more complete explanation of why this new column at the beginning of the dataset, see [here](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/issues/1340) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46379241/openrefine-create-a-shifted-copy-of-a-column).