# Sum all records of column in Openrefine?

Tags: openrefine, grel

I am trying to calculate the average of the records in a column to fill the missing data in that column. Searched a lot on Openrefine online resources but couldn't find anything.

Comment: OpenRefine is not the best tool for that, it's not a spreadsheet software nor a BI tool. But you can do this kind of calculation using methods explained here : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openrefine/CfNurLR5CII

Comment: @EttoreRizza Thanks for your reply. I understand its not BI tool. But I want to handle the missing values before using the data for my further needs.

Comment: @EttoreRizza I looked into the mentioned workaround but it works for record type data. I want the average of the whole column.

Comment: The real workaround is: you can transform any project in record type data. Add a column containing a constant (like "1"), blank down and put the column in the beginning. Now [your entire dataset is a single record](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46379602/5383863), and you can use column wise calculations with row.record.cells['colum name'].value